# Converting to a Recursive Function?

Tags: c++, math, recursion

I still have trouble with basic recursion. So I have two function shown as

```
unsigned long factorial(int x)
{
    // recursive function to find factorial 

    if(x==1)
        return 1; // base case 
    return x * (factorial(x-1)); // recursive call 
}


int choose(int choose, int choose_from)
{
    // function to find how many different ways to "choose"
    // calls factorial function multiple times

    return factorial(choose_from) / (factorial(choose) * factorial(choose_from - choose));
}
```

My instructor told me this is actually wrong and I should be recursing in the choose function. I don't see how since the choose formula is given as **C(n, r) = n! / (r! · (n – r)!)**, and since all that is being recursed is the factorials, I just made a separate factorial function.

How would these two functions, without using new libraries, become one recursive function?

Comment: There are almost an infinity of relationships between binomials. Pick one that seems suitably recursive. Use it.

Comment: Well, you don't need to compute the full factorials as you're doing now to compute C(n, r).  Write out the formula on paper and cancel out the values -- you should be left with just a few multiplications.  For example `C(52, 51)` -- you certainly don't need to calculation 52! and 51! to get the answer.

Comment: I think **a good way** to approach this is to present Pascal's triangle by computing each number from the previous one on that line, using a fixed number of arithmetical operations per number. The computation can use information such as the number's placement on the line. I remember doing this in high school (on an i8085 computer), so, it's very much doable, and instructive. This then gives you a relationship that can easily be expressed as a recursive formula. And then used in your `choose` function.

Answer (score 4):

I think your instructor wants you to use this [recurrent definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients):

```
C(N, 1) = N
C(N, K) = C(N, K-1) * (N + 1 - K) / K
```

This definition lets you avoid using factorial, recursing inside your `choose` function.

Comment: I'm wondering if the students were expected to be able to derive the recurrent definition. With a helper (entry) function, the number of recursions could be reduced by starting with C(N, K) = C(N, min(N-K, K)), where min() is the minimum value function. For example C(10,8) == C(10,2)

Comment: The recurrent definition should start with C(N, 0) = 1. See [boundary values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula)

Answer (score 1):

First please note that the argument order in your choose-function are switched compared to those in the C-function.

Now what your instructor means is that he wants the choose-function recursive for example like so:

```
C(n, r) = n! / (r! · (n – r)!) = n/(n-r) * (n-1)! / (r! · (n -1 – r)!) = n/(n-r)*C(n-1, r)
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf fixed

Comment: Oh. Well, C(n,r)=n*C(n-1,r) reduces to pure factorial, so also that's a bit wrong?